# Using mapping inside a .then()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am developing a app with Node/Express/Mongoose (fairly new to it) and I am trying to find out how I would map the returned users so I could use their information (I am counting mapping is the right way to retrieve the data. There's one field called numberOfJobs and I wanted to use it so I could make a sum of all of them. So far I am jusr console.log them which show me the all the users but I can't figure out how to access this info.

My code below:

```
app.get('/register', (req, res) => {
  Register.find({})
  .then(users => {
    console.log(users); // MAPPING HERE
  })
})
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, instead of logging the value, just do the mapping in that exact place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to reduce the array to a single value

```
app.get('/register', (req, res) => {
  Register.find({})
    .then(users => {
       const total = users.reduce((sum, { numberOfJobs }) => sum + numberOfJobs, 0);
       console.log(total);
    });
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Consider `map` method as a way of changing each element and return it into his place in existing array, for this you can use `forEach` for example:

```
app.get('/register', (req, res) => {
  Register.find({})
  .then(users => {
    let total = 0
    users.forEach(user=> total += user.numberOfJobs)
    console.log(total) // total amount
  })
})
```

Comment: Don't use `forEach`. `reduce` is a much better choice for this job, or in general use `for … of`.